# To plot the categorical columns to visualize them in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I have a categorical column with high number of classes, I want to visualize them in a small graph just to see how much the data is inconsistent, when I am plotting it some values are coming in white while some in the given color as shown below.

[image: Plot of categorical column with 300 different classes, maximum value is 3000 and minimum coube be 0]

The code I am using is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
plt.bar(keys_departure, values_departure, color ='maroon')
plt.show()
```

In the figure some lines are coming in 'maroon' color, while some of them are coming in white and there are many grey lines also all over the graph.

I don't want to increase the size and visualize, as I need to add this graph in report also. So I just want to visualize in small box.